# Doing calculations on summary elements

Tags: r

Is there an easy way to run followup mathematical calculations on elements of a summary?  I have log transformed data that is run through an anova analysis.  I would like to calculate the antilog of the summary output.

I have the following code:

```
require(multcomp)
inc <- log(Inc)
myanova <- aov(inc ~ educ)    
tukey <- glht(myanova, linfct = mcp(educ = "Tukey"))
summary(tukey)
```

Which produces an output as follows:

```
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
12 - under12 == 0      0.32787    0.08493   3.861  0.00104 ** 
13to15 - under12 == 0  0.49187    0.08775   5.606  < 0.001 ***
16 - under12 == 0      0.89775    0.09217   9.740  < 0.001 ***
over16 - under12 == 0  0.99856    0.09316  10.719  < 0.001 ***
13to15 - 12 == 0       0.16400    0.04674   3.509  0.00394 ** 
etc.
```

How can I easily execute an antilog calculation on the Estimate values?

Comment: have a look at `attributes(tukey)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, so I'd recommend further checking, but if all you want is to see exponented estimates and standard errors I think something similar to the following will work (I used different data).

```
> amod <- aov(breaks ~ tension, data = warpbreaks)
> tukey = glht(amod, linfct = mcp(tension = "Tukey"))

> tsum = summary(tukey)
> tsum[[10]]$coefficients = exp(tsum[[10]]$coefficients)
> tsum[[10]]$sigma = exp(tsum[[10]]$sigma)
> tsum
```

If you want to use coef(tukey) to give you the estimates then you would reverse transform with:

```
exp(coef(tukey))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
      coef(tukey)
```

to get the estimated values. here an example:

```
  amod <- aov(breaks ~ tension, data = warpbreaks)
  tukey <- glht(amod, linfct = mcp(tension = "Tukey"))
```

Now if want to get all tukey summary elements you type you apply `head` or `tail` to get a named list with the summary elements.

```
head(summary(tukey))
$model
Call:
   aov(formula = breaks ~ tension, data = warpbreaks)

Terms:
                 tension Residuals
Sum of Squares  2034.259  7198.556
Deg. of Freedom        2        51

Residual standard error: 11.88058 
Estimated effects may be unbalanced

$linfct
      (Intercept) tensionM tensionH
M - L           0        1        0
H - L           0        0        1
H - M           0       -1        1
attr(,"type")
[1] "Tukey"

$rhs
[1] 0 0 0

$coef
(Intercept)    tensionM    tensionH 
   36.38889   -10.00000   -14.72222 

$vcov
            (Intercept)  tensionM  tensionH
(Intercept)    7.841564 -7.841564 -7.841564
tensionM      -7.841564 15.683128  7.841564
tensionH      -7.841564  7.841564 15.683128

$df
[1] 51
```